# OpenCV (Python) not updating frame when read() is called

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

I am trying to pull individual frames at specified times from an RTSP feed.

This works fine for video streaming:

```
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL)

while(1):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

But if I want to take an image every second and save it by doing something like this:

```
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL)

for t in range(60):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imwrite("{}.jpg".format(t), frame)
    time.sleep(1);
```

Every image will look exactly the same as the first image. In every instance ret == True.

(Also this was working fine for me a week ago and then ipython did something that required me to do a re-install)

Comment: Do you mean `cv2.imwrite('t.jpg', frame)`?

Comment: ^^ Yes sorry, I fixed it... I had been moving back in between different libraries. But I had cv2.imwrite() in my actual code.

Comment: Don't you want to change the name of the image `t.jpg` on every iteration since its getting overwritten.

Comment: ^^ Yes yes... Sorry I wrote that from memory not an actual copy paste of my code. Just the smallest block that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.waitKey(1000)` wouldn't do anything if you didn't show image with `cv2.imshow()`. Try:

```
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL)

for t in range(60):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    cv2.imwrite('{}.jpg'.format(t), frame)

    # this will activate the waitKey funciton
    cv2.imshow('preview', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1000)
```

On another note, iPython/jupyter doesn't play well with the cv2's `imshow` and the whole GUI functionality. If, for example, you can't break the loop by keypress

```
if (cv2.waitKey(1000) == 27 & 0xff): break;
```

Comment: Alright, well if I replace cv2.waitKey(1000) with time.sleep(1)? I don't want to show anything, just want to wait one second.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after endless messing with it over the last few days, 1 second is not fast enough for the feed for whatever reason.

This will work:

```
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL)

for t in range(60):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    if ret and t % 1000 == 0:
        cv2.imwrite("{}.jpg".format(t), frame)
    time.sleep(0.001)
```